# Should I use multithreading to copy sheet records to another sheet?

Tags: python, multithreading, xlsx

I have half a million record of data in an excel sheet. Based on their quality I want to seperate those records into two sheet. If a record has all of its column filled with some valid data,then it would go to one sheet,else to the other sheet.

I found that, it is best to use a method to seperate these records and store them in seperate arrays,then to use another method to insert those values to other sheets.for the purpose of learning more about multithreading, in the following code i have also added another method that finds sheet row number of good and bad records,then store them in seperate lists, which will be used by the previously mentioned methods to store data in another set of seperate lists.

my first method, that finds row numbers:

```
def seperate_data(last_row=0):
    for i in range(last_row):
        if old_sheet.cell(i, 1).value != '' and old_sheet.cell(i, 3).value != '' and old_sheet.cell(i, 4).value != '':
            li_good.append(i)
        else:
            li_bad.append(i)
```

if a record from ith row contains all data at columns 1, 3 and 4 then the record's  row number would be stored in li good.

second and third method:

```
def get_good_data():
    for i in li_good:
        data_good.append([old_sheet.cell(i, 0).value, old_sheet.cell(i, 1).value, old_sheet.cell(i, 2).value,
                          old_sheet.cell(i, 3).value, old_sheet.cell(i, 4).value, old_sheet.cell(i, 5).value,
                          old_sheet.cell(i, 6).value])

def get_bad_data():
    for i in li_bad:
        data_bad.append([old_sheet.cell(i, 0).value, old_sheet.cell(i, 1).value, old_sheet.cell(i, 2).value,
                         old_sheet.cell(i, 3).value, old_sheet.cell(i, 4).value, old_sheet.cell(i, 5).value,
                         old_sheet.cell(i, 6).value])
```

Then, I would copy contents from data_good and data_bad to good and bad sheet using my 4th(add_good_data) and 5th method(add_bad_data)

My Question is, should I create 5 seperate threads for each method and then run them concurrently? First, I tried it without the thread.join() method, but I didn't get the expected result.Then I ran the code again with join(), and the code worked correctly.I noticed that, using join() actually makes that thread to wait until the completion of previously started thread,which makes it as a usual sequential execution. Am I implementing the multithreading strategy correctly? When should i use multithreading?

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to create, run and wait for threads? That's the important part here.

Comment: Just a question, are you storing the good and bad data on separate sheets of the same XLSX file or on separate XLSX files?

Comment: @Luc I am using two different xlsx files

Comment: @MatthiasFripp I am new to the concept of multithreading. I created 5 threads, then started them all using start() and join() commands.I didn't use waits in any of my methods.

Comment: It would help if you show the actual code you are running. It won't work if you start a thread, then join it, then start another, then join it, etc. Then your main code will wait till each thread finishes before starting the next. You also can't run each of these methods in separate threads at the same time, since they need results from each other. If you have a lot of files the best option is to process each one in its own thread. If you have one big file and single threading is too slow, you may need to have separate threads process different parts of it. But parallel writing will be tricky.

Comment: @MatthiasFripp what is the purpose of multithreading then? I thought the multiple threads here would effectively share their memories, and as I add data to a list in one of the thread, the other threads using that list would automatically get updated. my code - [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fef3Q2S8C9l9u4fP3ozyd2MHsi19cB0v/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Currently, each of your methods expects all the data to be processed by the previous method before it runs. To go faster, you need to arrange for data to flow between the methods as they run, with all of them running in parallel. The easiest way to do that is probably to use [queues](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) to pass items from one method to another. e.g., `separate_data` would put everything into `good` and `bad` queues, then the other methods would have loops that read items from those queues and process them. Launch all 3 methods in separate threads then join all 3.

Comment: You should also know that standard threading will only speed up the code if the time-consuming step releases Python's Global Interpreter Lock. This is probably true if it is waiting for IO or is running C code (e.g., numpy operations). But if both threads are intensively running Python code, they will each halt till the other yields control. In this case, you may need to use multiprocessing instead of standard threading. Then you should use `multiprocessing.Queue` instead of `queue.Queue` to communicate between the workers. But that `pickle`s the data, which may eat up the speed gains.